# getting the link but images not getting downloaded

Tags: php, mysql

I am fairly new at this, I was trying to display and download images stored in database as a image path. the display works fine but when I try to download the images from the download button the URL shows the full path of the image but the download dosent happen.

```
$sql_img = "SELECT * FROM cms
            JOIN images ON cms.C_ID = images.C_ID
            WHERE B_Name = '$select'";
$sql_img_run = mysqli_query($con, $sql_img);

            ?>
            
            <table class="display_img">
                    <tr>
                        <th>Image ID</th>
                        <th>Cms ID</th>
                        <th>Images</th>
                    </tr>

            <?php

            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql_img_run)) {

                $img_id = $row['Img_ID'];
                $image = $row['Image'];
                $cms_id = $row['C_ID'];
            
                // $path = "C:\xampp\htdocs\Airan\Api\";
                $path = "http://localhost/Airan/api/";
                ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td><?php echo $img_id ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $cms_id ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo '<img height="100" src='.$path.$image.'>'?></td>
                        <td>
                            <a href="home.php?Image=<?php echo $path.$image; ?>" class="btn-primary download-btn">Download</a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
```

I have tried various methods but nothing works.

Comment: You probably need to post the code for `home.php` for anyone to be able to help. Maybe show some of the "various methods" too.

Comment: Is the above code your actual code ( or in same order )? You have HTML content **before** calling `header`

Comment: Your code is also potentially vulnerable to SQL injection

Comment: there is code above but it is for displaying other data, which is working perfectly fine. the only issue I am getting is when I am trying to download the displayed images. when I click on the download button it shows something like this in url :http://localhost/Airan/home.php?Image=http://localhost/Airan/api/uploads/2023-05-08/download1.jpg this path is correct but the image is not being downloaded. if you want full code for reference I can post it too @ProfessorAbronsius

Comment: If you are outputting HTML content **before** calling the `header` function you will encounter issues unless you use output buffering and flush the buffer before calling `header`. It would be better to have the PHP that sends the file before **any** HTML content... ie: at the top

Comment: Actually this is not going to be live hence there are no issues with SQL injections, I am trying to clear basic concepts. As you've suggested I have included the header files on the top of the HTML code to avoid any issues. It was a nice tip and would help in me in further projects. but the issue of images not getting downloaded still stands. @ProfessorAbronsius

Comment: An unclosed `<button>` inside `<a>`? `method` as a button attribute? That never works. Remove the button part

Comment: if I remove the button. how would I trigger the download? @brombeer

Comment: There's an `<a>` surrounding your button that should do it. Add a [download attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#attributes) to it

Comment: Do you mean like this? I have removed the button tag and added the button attribute in the `<a>` tag itself
`<td>
<a href="home.php?Image=<?php echo $path.$image; ?>" class="btn-primary download-btn" download>
</td>`
This downloads the whole page @brombeer

Comment: Sorry, didn't read your code properly, my fault. No need for the `download` attribute, your `home.php` handles downloading. `$_POST` will not be available though, use `$_GET`. Good luck

Comment: I tried using `$_GET` but same thing happens.  page reloads and nothing is downloaded. @brombeer

Comment: No output before any [header](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) call, as Professor Abronsius already mentioned. Move that part to the top, above any content.

Comment: By applying `$_GET` and moving the header files to the top it does not recognize the variables `$path` and `$image`. gives an error of undefined variables. @brombeer

Comment: Do you have `allow_url_fopen` enabled? You're trying to read from an URL, not a local filesystem (might want to change the path to the file, it seems to be on the same server)

Comment: Why would you need `$path` and `$image` in your download code? You'd want to get the name from your URL.

Comment: I am trying to read from local file system. `$image` stores the path for the dynamically created folder in which the images are stored and `$path` stores the common path. I have edited and put the full code file for your reference. @brombeer

Comment: I know. Again, you don't need/want to use `$path` and `$image` when the image has already been set in the URL. Use `$file = $_GET['Image'];` instead of `$file = $path.$image;`. Good luck

Comment: Also, I don't think `header('location: home.php');` is really needed when downloading

Comment: is the any possible way I could connect with you @ProfessorAbronsius

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the solutions to this was purely simple. only adding the `download` attribute to the `<a>` was downloading the whole page because there was no specific path given to the `download` attribute.

`<a download="<?php echo $path.$image; ?>" href="<?php echo $path.$image; ?>" class="btn-primary download-btn">Download</a>`

This works like a charm.

Thankyou guys, you gave your precious time to help resolve the issue. I did get to learn a lot of things from you guys. It wouldn't have been possible without you guys.

Answer (score 0):

An example, using hardcoded image paths and nonsense IDs to emulate what you might be drawing from the database.

Use the GET method as you are using a hyperlink with `Image` parameter in querystring.

Do not output HTML ( or any content ) before calling `header` function unless you explicitly flush the buffers before.

Add the `download` attribute to each hyperlink.

```
<?php

    error_reporting( E_ALL );
    ini_set( 'display_errors', 1 );
    
    
    # simple function to read file and send the binary contents
    function sendfile( $filename=NULL, $filepath=NULL ){
        if( file_exists( $filepath ) ){
            if( !is_file( $filepath ) or connection_status()!=0 ) return FALSE;
            header('Content-Type: application/image');
            header('Content-Length:'.filesize( $filepath ) );
            header("Content-Length: ".(string)( filesize( $filepath ) ) );
            header("Content-Disposition: attachement; filename={$filename}");
            header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary\n");
            if( $file = @fopen( $filepath, 'rb' ) ) {
                while( !@feof( $file ) and ( connection_status()==0 ) ) {
                    print( fread( $file, 1024*8 ) );
                    flush();
                }
                @fclose( $file );
            }
            return( ( connection_status()==0 ) and !connection_aborted() );
        }
    }
    
    /*
        intercept the GET request, read the `Image` parameter
        and call the above function.
    */
    if( isset( $_GET['Image'] ) ){
        
        $name=pathinfo( $_GET['Image'], PATHINFO_BASENAME );
        $path=__DIR__ . '/'. $_GET['Image'];
        
        # send the file and terminate.
        exit( sendfile( $name, $path ) );
    }
?>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8' />
        <title>Download images...</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!--
            in this example images are located within a sub-directory of the current
            working script. The sub-folder is called "carousel" - the images are sequentially
            named using numbers (that is not important here however)
        -->
        <table class='display_img'>
            <tr>
                 <th>Image ID</th>
                 <th>Cms ID</th>
                 <th>Images</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                 <td>1</td>
                 <td>23</td>
                 <td><img height="100" src='./images/carousel/01.jpg'></td>
                 <td><a href='?Image=images/carousel/01.jpg' download><button class="btn-primary download-btn" name="download_btn">Download</a></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                 <td>2</td>
                 <td>23</td>
                 <td><img height="100" src='./images/carousel/02.jpg'></td>
                 <td><a href='?Image=images/carousel/02.jpg' download><button class="btn-primary download-btn" name="download_btn">Download</a></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                 <td>3</td>
                 <td>23</td>
                 <td><img height="100" src='./images/carousel/03.jpg'></td>
                 <td><a href='?Image=images/carousel/03.jpg' download><button class="btn-primary download-btn" name="download_btn">Download</a></td>
            </tr>       
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```